# How to get the address of a range with multiple subranges, including the sheet name in EACH subrange?

Tags: excel, vba

With the union statement I created a range existing of multiple subranges, of `Worksheet("data")`. I need that range for calculations on another worksheet, `Worksheet("weekly")`. Therefore I want the address of the range including the sheet name in each subrange. `rRng` is my range existing of several subranges.

```
rRng.Address(External:=True) returns: "data!$D$1570:$D$1575,$D$2992:$D$3000,$D$5979:$D$5988"
```

However, to calculate the average of the cells in this range I need:  `"data!$D$1570:$D$1575,data!$D$2992:$D$3000,data!$D$5979:$D$5988"`

The only solution I found so far is:

```
Dim range_string As String
range_string = ""

Dim SubRange As range
For Each SubRange In rRng
    range_string = range_string & SubRange.Address(External:=True) & ","
Next SubRange
range_string = Left(range_string, (Len(range_string) - 1))

Worksheets("weekly").range("$C2").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & range_string & ")"
```

There must be a more easy way. Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Sandra

Comment: Hi Sandra. It may be easier to build the string while creating the `rRng` from multiple subranges using the `Union` statement rather than trying to create it afterwards. Can you post the code showing how the `rRng` is created?

Answer (score 1):

Each of those subranges is called an Area. You can loop through the Areas of a range and build the string.  Here's an example.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rArea As Range
    Dim sForm As String

    'union the ranges
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("D1570:d1575")
    Set rng = Union(rng, Sheet1.Range("D2992:d3000"))

    'loop through the areas and build the string
    For Each rArea In rng.Areas
        sForm = sForm & rArea.Address(, , , True) & ","
    Next rArea

    'remove the last comma
    sForm = Left$(sForm, Len(sForm) - 1)

    'insert the formula
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & sForm & ")"

    Debug.Print Sheet2.Range("A1").Formula

End Sub
```

The debug.print produces:

```
=AVERAGE(data!$D$1570:$D$1575,data!$D$2992:$D$3000)
```